# Change size of popup jpg.image in content.ftl?

Tags: geoserver

I have created a Geoserver layer in Openlayers that when clicked, opens up the attribute table and a jpg. image. However, the image is too large, obscurring the attribute table and title. Is it possible to adjust the size with Freemarker in the content.ftl file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: yes, it's possible - what have you tried so far?

Comment: It might be simpler to limit the width/height of images in the css for the element where you display the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: Thanks for the answers. First I looked in content.ftl and header.ftl to change it but I found a piece of code in css to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Used this in CSS to adjust the size:

```
<style>
    img {
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
        -o-object-fit: contain;
        object-position: top;
        -o-object-position: top;
    }

</style>
```